# EJS CSS Not loading front end

Tags: javascript, css

So i set the middleware and static folder for the .css file, but when i attempt to use it and load it in the EJS file i receive an error in the chrome debugger saying under "network" that it was cancelled.

app.js

```
// view engine
exapp.set('view engine', 'ejs');
exapp.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
console.log('Static location: ' + path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// body parser 
exapp.use(bodyParser.json());
exapp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// set static path
exapp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
console.log('Static location: ' + path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
exapp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
console.log('Static location: ' + path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'));

// get requests
exapp.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.render('index');
})

exapp.get('/about', function(request, response){
    response.render('about');
})
```

header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Unicorn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
    
<body>
```

Picture of what i found in the chrome debugging thing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it

For some unknown reason i need to add **'/public/css'** as the first parameter to the `use()` function

Original

```
exapp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
```

Fixed

```
exapp.use('/public/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
```

Hope this helps others :)